# problema para conectar eclipse con base de datos

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas noches, soy autodidacta en el tema de java y ando buscando una solución para esta excepción "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature" la cual salta en el momento de intentar conectar una base de datos con mi codigo en java, realmente ya le descargué el jar de mysql 5.0.8 y nada, le instalé el aspectj desde el instalador de software de eclipse y tampoco, realmente ya no se que hacer, puesto que no solo no me deja conectar a mysql, tampoco a ucanaccess el cual lo tengo como segunda opción si mysql me presenta problemas. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué instalaste `aspectj`? ¿Vas a trabajar con Spring? Si es un programa normal de Java, con que bajes [el jar para JDBC actualizado](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.18) no necesitas nada más.

Comment: "conectar eclipse con base de datos" y "conectar una base de datos con mi código en java" son dos cosas muy distintas, explica mejor que quieres hacer

Comment: A. Cedano, gracias por tu aporte, intenté lo que me dices, no me da la conexion igual, pero ahora es por esto the JAR file C:\Program Files\Java\Jre1.8.0_151\ext\mysql-connector-java-8.07-dmr-bin.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below, he estado leyendo sobre esto y veo que es algo con el jdk, pero no tengo claro a que se refieren, ¿me puedes ayudar por favor?